# Finding all csv links from website using R

Tags: r, csv, download

I am trying to download the datafiles from ICE website (https://www.theice.com/clear-us/risk-management#margin-rates) containing info on margin strategy. I tried to do so by appliying the following code in R:

```
page <- read_html("https://www.theice.com/clear-us/risk-management#margin-rates")
raw_list <- page %>% # takes the page above for which we've read the html
html_nodes("a") %>%  # find all links in the page
html_attr("href") %>% # get the url for these links
str_subset("\\.csv") # find those that end in csv only
```

However, it only finds two csv files. That is, it doesn't detect any files displayed when clicking at *Margin Rates* and going to *Historic ICE Risk Model Parameter*. See below

```
raw_list
[1] "/publicdocs/iosco_reporting/haircut_history/icus/ICUS_Asset_Haircuts_History.csv"   
[2] "/publicdocs/iosco_reporting/haircut_history/icus/ICUS_Currency_Haircuts_History.csv"
```

I am wondering how I can do that so later on I can select the files and download them.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can look at the network traffic in browser devtools to find the url for each dropdown action.

The *Historic ICE Risk Model Parameter* dropdown pulls from this page:
https://www.theice.com/marginrates/ClearUSMarginParameterFiles.shtml;jsessionid=7945F3FE58331C88218978363BA8963C?getParameterFileTable&category=Historical

We remove the `jsessionid` (per QHarr's comment) and use that as our endpoint:

```r
endpoint <- "https://www.theice.com/marginrates/ClearUSMarginParameterFiles.shtml?getParameterFileTable&category=Historical"
page <- read_html(endpoint)
```

Then we can get the full csv list:

```r
raw_list <- page %>%
    html_nodes(".table-partitioned a") %>% # add specificity as QHarr suggests
    html_attr("href")
```

Output:

```
'/publicdocs/clear_us/irmParameters/ICUS_MARGIN_INTERMONTH_20210310.CSV'
'/publicdocs/clear_us/irmParameters/ICUS_MARGIN_INTERCONTRACT_20210310.CSV'
'/publicdocs/clear_us/irmParameters/ICUS_MARGIN_SCANNING_20210310.CSV'
'/publicdocs/clear_us/irmParameters/ICUS_MARGIN_STRATEGY_20210310.CSV'
'/publicdocs/clear_us/irmParameters/ICUS_MARGIN_INTERMONTH_20210226.CSV'
'/publicdocs/clear_us/irmParameters/ICUS_MARGIN_INTERCONTRACT_20210226.CSV'
'/publicdocs/clear_us/irmParameters/ICUS_MARGIN_SCANNING_20210226.CSV'
'/publicdocs/clear_us/irmParameters/ICUS_MARGIN_STRATEGY_20210226.CSV'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the page does not load that part of the page instantly and it is missing in your request. The network monitor indicates that a file "ClearUSRiskArrayFiles.shtml" is being loaded 400 ms later. That file seems to provide the required links once you specify year and month in the URL.

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

page <- read_html("https://www.theice.com/iceriskmodel/ClearUSRiskArrayFiles.shtml?getRiskArrayTable=&type=icus&year=2021&month=03")

raw_list <- page %>% # takes the page above for which we've read the html
  html_nodes("a") %>%  # find all links in the page
  html_attr("href")

head(raw_list[grepl("csv", raw_list)], 3L)
#> [1] "/publicdocs/irm_files/icus/2021/03/NYB0312E.csv.zip"
#> [2] "/publicdocs/irm_files/icus/2021/03/NYB0311E.csv.zip"
#> [3] "/publicdocs/irm_files/icus/2021/03/NYB0311F.csv.zip"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jan. I tried this but I keeps reading only the two files shown above. See here `raw_list <- page %>% # takes the page above for which we've read the html
+ html_nodes("a") %>%  # find all links in the page
+ html_attr("href") %>% # get the url for these links
+ str_subset("\\.[cC][sS][vV]$") 
> raw_list
[1] "/publicdocs/iosco_reporting/haircut_history/icus/ICUS_Asset_Haircuts_History.csv"   
[2] "/publicdocs/iosco_reporting/haircut_history/icus/ICUS_Currency_Haircuts_History.csv"`

Comment: You are right. It was something else. I found a way to get to the missing files. However, you won't get all the files in one gulp with this.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your time Jan